# Why should we use svn switch?

Tags: svn

I have svn repo with branches, tags and trunk 
Now when i create new branch,
Is it must to use svn switch to that branch? 
Should i Not work on that branch directory directly?

Sorry if it sounds stupid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the SVN Switch functionality is not that useless.

There might be times when you have huge codebase located in multiple branches of a release.

Consider a scenario:

You have a branch named **Release X** and for some purpose, you create another branch **Release X.1** from it.

If a developer wants to work with X.1 Branch now, he has two options:

1. Checkout the whole branch and the complete codebase (Time consumuing?)
2. SVN Switch on **Release X** working copy to point to **Release X.1** (Considering there are no huge changes) - Works like a charm!
3. Once finished with the work, switch back seamlessly to previous branch...

This was one of the scenario ... What happens when you relocate your repository? The whole URL changes. Switching is intelligent rather checkout.

I believe I have made my point :)

Comment: hmm i think i get it now. but for small cases like mine. I can work on branches directly right?

Comment: But if `trunk` is switched to a branch, isn't access to `trunk` then lost until one remember to switch back to `trunk`?  It sounds a little 'hacker' like to make that kind of back stage contents changes, while keeping the `trunk` directory name.

Comment: Yes, that's true. So, the good idea would be to check the current SVN branch you are on using `svn info` command.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it must to use svn switch to that branch?

Not "must", even not "have" in terms of RFCs. You *can* switch WC, but "switch-or-not-to-switch" is **heavy workflow- and style- and situation-dependent**

Some dry well-known theory

- Every WC have one (at the moment) <strike>Repository Root</strike>**URL** attribute
- We can not operate in WC (without tricks) with objects below <strike>RepoRoot</strike>URL
- While tags and branches are cheap copy inside repository, they are not cheap (in common case) inside Working Copies and waste the same space as "originals"
- You can select any node in repository as root of your Working Copy depending on your preferences
- You can use any amount of Working Copies (1+) for different parts of your repository

All above leads to the fact that:

- You can use *one WC all time* (less space, more traffic and update time on switching), rooted to *some node* deep inside repository-tree and **switch** this WC to other nodes on demand
- You can use *one WC per unrelated node* (more space, less traffic - no switch, no needs for syncing WC after switch) and **change WC**
- You can (in some cases) have WC of the whole repository from root (biggest space and traffic usage in case of frequent changes in tags/branches side, useless unused parts of repo in WC) and **navigate on the single WC-tree**

As you can see, switch is a must only in 1/3 of situations

Answer (score 1):

assuming your repo looks a bit like this:

```
.
├── branches/
│   ├── branch1/
│   │   └── src/
│   └── branch2/
│       └── src/
└── trunk/
    └── src/
```

If you've checked out the whole repo then the branch will just appear as another sub-directory as you say.

However the usual way of working is to just checkout the trunk, then svn switch to the branch and svn switch back.  This way you don't have to check out so much data, your ide always looks at the same directory and you don't get confused and accidentally edit the wrong branch.

Personally where I *have* to use branches I checkout each one to separate directories side by side in my workspace directory. But mostly I avoid branching.